# Cypress - Xpath

Tags: xpath, cypress

I am new to cypress and wanted to use xpath for my element locators.

How can I declare my objects using xpath ? I currently have a design like this.
How can I use xpath for my username and submitBtn elements?

```
export default class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    
    username     = "#username";
    submitBtn = "#_submit";
    
    fillLoginUser(myUser) {
        let field = cy.get(this.username);
        field.clear();
        field.type(Cypress.env(myUser));
        
        this.submit(this.submitBtn)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin for the [xpath](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath)

**Install with npm**

```
npm install -D cypress-xpath
```

**Include in your project's cypress/support/index.js**

```
require('cypress-xpath')
```

You can use cy.xpath instead of cy.get .

```
  cy.xpath('//ul[@class="todo-list"]//li')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Rahul

however, I think this won't work when using outside it(...)
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Check https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/ .

Comment: In 2022, Cypress Ver-Ver- 10.9.0,  code snippet- require('cypress-xpath') will go to file e2e.js in the support folder as folder hierarchy has been changed in the latest version.